# Netbeans 6.5 prevents adding breakpoints to Java files. Configuration issue?

Tags: java, netbeans6.5

I'm not able to add breakpoints to any Java file. 
It seems this problem has been reported in slightly varying contexts in the netbeans issuezilla. I could not find any concrete workarounds other than updgrade to NB6.7M2, which is currently not feasible.

Other things I've tried are a JDK updgrade, spicy bat wings and a bottle of silvermoon port (multiple system restarts ;))

I was just wondering if any of the gurus at SO had encountered this problem before and if it is some configuration that got messed up during ide updates/project svn updates etc.

NB build version : 20081110001
Java: 1.6.0__14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did some more investigating and found that an error in Netbeans update had de-activated most of my Java plugins, one of which was ... "Java Debugging"

Activating the plugin solved the issue.

"Oh. Well I feel sheepish. [turns into a sheep]" - Genie (Aladdin)

For reference, the setting is found in Tools > Plugins > Installed (tab) , under the "Java" category

Comment: You might not have enough rep to be able to edit your own responses, but if you could have modified your question it would have been better.  Next time!